# Adding custom attributes to states and a dropdown to cities

Tags: magento2, custom-attributes, address, country-regions

I would like to change the way the **users enter addresses**, and I have several doubts about the best way to do it.

First, I need to add a **drop down** for states/provinces to other countries, for what I've seen this is completely database work. Is this correct?

I also need that instead of typing the city, the user gets to select the desired city from a select input. I suppose this would be achieved by creating a new model with its table, and such table is related to the states/provinces. I think this is the right way to do so.

Then, I also need to add some custom attributes to the states, a special code. I don't think I can use EAV, for what I've seen states is no extensible. Do I have to modify the table (or add a new table that references state) to add the new attributes? or is there a simpler way to implement this?

Thanks.